# Why doesn't is operator take in consideration if the explicit operator is overriden when checking types?

Tags: c#

Consider this code sample:

```
public class Human {    
    public string Value { get; set;}
}
public class Car { 

    public static explicit operator Human (Car c) { 

        Human h = new Human();

        h.Value = "Value from Car";
        return h;
    }
}

public class Program { 
public static void Mani() { 
        Car c = new Car();

        Human h = (Human)c;
        Console.WriteLine("h.Value = {0}", h.Value);
        Console.WriteLine(c is Human);
}
}
```

Up I provide a possibility of an explicit cast from Car to Human, though Car and Human hierarchically are not related! The above code simply means that **"Car is convertible to human"**

However, if you run the snippet you will find the expression `c is Human` evaluates to false! [I used to believe that the is operator is kinda expensive cause it attempts to do an actual cast](http://galilyou.blogspot.com/2010/03/usage-of-is-operator-should-be-handled.html) that might result in an `InvalidCastException`. If the operator is trying to cast, then the cast should succeed as there's an operator logic that should perform the cast! 
What does "is" test? 
Does test a hierarchical **"is-a"** relationship? 
 
Does test whether a variable type **"is convertible to"** a type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is` operator tests for an actual type relation, not for 'can cast'. Rightfully so.

As for the 'how does it do it' part: I don't know but I assume there are more efficient ways (reflection) to test for family ties than letting it come to an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the is operator only considers reference conversions, boxing conversions, and unboxing conversions. Other conversions, such as user-defined conversions, are not considered.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Henk's answer, I guess reflection should provide some method to check whether a user-defined cast exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `is` operator never throws exceptions. It does the exact same thing as the related `as` operator except that it converts the result to a boolean.  The `is` and `as` operators are very fast if you are doing an up-cast because the CLR in that case knows what types are compatible.  If you are down-casting the cast is a bit slower.

Normal casting (i.e. `Mytype o2 = (Mytype) o1;`) does the same as the `as` operator but it may throw an InvalidCastException.

In your case where you have defined an explicit cast operator you have to use the normal cast operator.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense:

You are checking the car object to a human type. If they'are the same or the same kind (if object inherits the human type) then it would have return true.

> The keyword is therefore used to check
>   for type compatibility, usually before
>   casting (converting) a source type to
>   a destination type in order to ensure
>   that won't cause a type-cast exception
>   to be thrown. Using is on a null
>   variable always returns false.

from [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Sharp_Programming/Keywords/is)